# How to cancel sending data while the username is taken

Tags: javascript, html

When someone fills out my registration form and the username is taken, it refreshes the page and says "The username is taken, choose another".

But all the data that the person filled in is removed.

How can I stop the refreshing if the username is taken, so the user can just change it?

```
protected string msg = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
        string LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
        string PhoneNumber = Request.Form["PhoneNumber"];
        string Prefix = Request.Form["Prefix"];
        PhoneNumber = Prefix + PhoneNumber;
        int BirthYear = int.Parse(Request.Form["BirthYear"]);
        string Email = Request.Form["Email"];
        string UserName = Request.Form["UserName"];
        string Password = Request.Form["Password"];
        string gender = Request.Form["gender"];
        string dbPath = this.MapPath("App_Data/Database.mdf");
        DAL dal = new DAL(dbPath);
        UtilityUser uu = new UtilityUser(dal);
        if (uu.Exist(UserName))
        {
            msg = "שם המשתמש שבחרת תפוס"; **//username is taken**
        }
        else
        {
            uu.Register(FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, BirthYear, Email, UserName, Password, gender);
            msg = "נרשמת בהצלחה!"; **// Register succeed**
        }
    }
}
```

This is the form to check for username:

```
var UserName = aspnetForm.UserName.value;
    if (UserName.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("labelUserName").innerHTML = '<img src=\'images/X.png\'>'; //**X icon**
        Fields += "שם משתמש - שדה זה חייב להכיל בין 6 ל־12 תווים\n";
        correct = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("labelUserName").innerHTML = '<img src=\'images/V.png\'>'; //**V icon**
    }
```

Comment: Use ajax to check username

Comment: Can you help me with that? How to use ajax or something?

Comment: @Ran check my answer and let me know what server side technology u are using so I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ajax for this functionality. Checking username availability is always an ajax call. You don't need to send all the data to the server. This just does not seem right

if you are using asp.net webforms then simply use page methods. Following is the code

Your Web Method

```
 using System.Web.Services;

 namespance namespacename{
 class your classname
 {

 [WebMethod]
 public static string checkAV(string uname)
  {
    //Your sql plus other logic

     if(userAVailable){return "true";}
     else{return "false";}

  }
```

You HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="txtUN" placeholder="username" onchange="return check();"/>
```

Your Javascript

```
 function check()
 {
    PageMethods.checkAV($(#txtUN"").val(),success,fail);
 }

 function success(response)
 {
   if(response=="false")
   {
     $("#r").html("user available");
   }
   else
   {$("#r").html("user not available");}
 }

 function fail(error){alert("error occured");}
```

And you need to use this in your script Manager

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: i am using javascript and c#, but i can learn ajax if you say it's not that hard?

Comment: are u using asp.net MVC or Webforms?

Comment: I have updated my answer using asp.net webforms through webforms functionality called "PageMethods"

Comment: Seems good but can you explain me it with more words so I can understand the meaning behind the commands, if you have time for it of course. I mean, what is Methods at all? Why you use $?

Comment: "r" is a span element. either user exist or not that reponse will be added to span "r". and I used Jquery to access the span element. this is how to access dom elements: $("#r").html(value to be assigned); and for details on page methods you can see here http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do s.t like this:

```
$("#formId").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.aspx",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    }).done(function(data) {
    if(data check)
        $("#formId").submit();
  });
});
```

You should create a method(web service) to check username that id your url above. Then if returned data is valid, submit your form or you can create another web service and do submit by it

Comment: is that ajax or javascript?

Comment: of course, that's simple to learning. I suggest you [w3school](http://www.w3school.com)